# FXM is not creating "sc_ext_contact" cookie on external site

Tags: fxm

We have multisite setup on Sitecore, example `www.MainsiteA.com` and `www.MainsiteB.com`, We have installed FXM beacon javascript code into couple of external sites, Both external sites are on sub-domain of the main sites:

1. book.MainsiteA.com
2. book.MainsiteB.com

My expectation that a user visiting `www.MainsiteA.com` then visits `book.MainsiteA.com` would have the same contact id, Same for `www.MainsiteB.com` and `book.MainsiteB.com`.

The issue we are seeing that one of the external sites does not create **sc_ext_contact** cookie that holds the contact id of the visitor,  while the other site is creating that cookie fine.

We need this cookie as we are collecting information about the user on the external sites and we need to merge that into the same contact in xDB at later stage, we would use the contact Id stored in the **sc_ext_contact** cookie.

Would there be any restrictions that could prevent FXM from creating the Cookie on the external site?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any answers for this?

Comment: @NilPun i posted the answer below, this was unique to an issue on the external site, but maybe it would give you an idea where to look for

Answer (score 2):

We are able to fix this issue, though it was unique to our case, i thought it might be helpful to others who might have this problem.

In FXM js code, the following code tries to set the `sc_ext_contact` cookie:

```
cookies.set(extCookieName, resp.ContactId, { expires: new Date(Date.parse(e.ContactExpires)), path: '/' });
```

the `Date.parse(e.ContactExpires)` method was always returning null  resulting in the cookie never being created, This was caused by custom js extension on the **external site** for the `Date` class that was not parsing the date format that sitecore was returning correctly, After accounting for that date format in the external site, the cookie was then created correctly